# WPF How to bind list to itemscontrol with each item being paired to a customcontrol and bound to the ith item in list

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol

I was wondering how I bind to the ith element of a list I am using for itemscontrol.

My code looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name ="Signalviewer_Control" ItemsSource="{Binding Source = {StaticResource signal_data}, Path = list_of_signals}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <wpfExp:SignalViewer Signal={StaticResource signal_data}, Path=list_of_signals[i]/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Needless to say I don't think list_of_signals[i] is valid syntax. But basically what i want to do is make itemscontrol create its default stackpanel in which each item from the list creates a new signalviewer. I then want to bind the created signalviewer's dependency property that I made to the signaldata in the static resource. However, I do not know how to access the specific signal that corresponds to the ith signalviewer.

Thanks for any help.

edit: Maybe it has to be done in code behind? I just wanted to know whether it was possible using just xaml though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` for each UI item in the `ItemsControl` will automatically be assigned to the corresponding Data Item in the source Collection. Therefore this is valid and will work:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name ="Signalviewer_Control" ItemsSource="{Binding Source = {StaticResource signal_data}, Path = list_of_signals}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <wpfExp:SignalViewer Signal="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I wanted to ask one more question. In my situation, is it more logical for me to just create a custom control that inherits from itemscontrol?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet No. subclassing WPF controls is usually a bad idea unless you have all the right reasons (such as a custom UI functionality that cannot be achieved by any standard WPF means). For example, a [Circular Panel](http://www.codebullets.com/custom-circle-panel-wpf-part-1-216). Subclassing controls just to set some properties (or to change appearance as you would do in ancient traditional frameworks) makes no sense at all and reduces maintainability.